# 504 Gateway Timeout ffmpeg video compression

Tags: php, ffmpeg, http-status-code-504

I have a PHP script that use the ffmpeg to compress mov file and convert in mp4.

When I upload a 1gb file, this is converted and in the end appears in console 504 (Gateway Timeout).
The instruction I use is this:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("$ffmpegPath -i $UploadedFilePath -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast  -filter:v scale=426:-2 $convertUrl 2>&1");
```

How can I do?
I would like the videos to be reduced considerably while maintaining good quality and without overloading the server.
The PHP parameters can be found at this link:
https://artruism.me/test.php

**UPDATE**

The call to the script is with ajaxForm

Comment: 504 happens when the loadbalancer drops the IP connection after it detected no traffic on the wire for X minutes (max LB timeout is 5 minutes). So, if your code is working for 5 minutes straight, and does not make any output, the LB will think "oh, the webserver won't respond" and drops the connection... others are also in need :)

Comment: Ok but what parameters should I increase to prevent it from going into timeout?
The PHP parameters can be found at this link: https://artruism.me/test.php

Comment: Parameters are irrelevant... the code must not run longer than the timeout or it needs to send data to the client ( heartbeat). If it takes longer than the timeout, don't start it through the web. A cronjob would do...

Comment: The script does not exceed the timeout time.
The script ended all the operations.
The client gives 504 after the server has finished

Comment: then there is another server in the chain of communication, which disconnects...

Comment: There is no other server.
This error only gives it for very large files and if I insert the compression with ffmpeg.
If I set max_execution_time to 0, the error ERR_NETWORK_IO_SUSPENDED appears.
The call to the script is with ajaxForm